# parse-server on newer (>= 7) node version

Tags: node.js, async-await, version, parse-server

Is running parse-server on a newer version of node (say >= 7) a supported configuration?

I ask since the docker image uses a version 6.x. I'd like to move to a higher version to allow async / await logic in Cloud Code, but would probably avoid it if there's a reason not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their releases page, the minimum node version with parse-server v 2.7.0 is node 6.11.4.

There is no documented max version.